# How to do on-behalf-of auth in .NET Core (missing BootstrapContext)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I've run the on-behalf-of sample in .NET 4.5:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof

But I need to do the same thing in .NET core.  When trying to port the sample service to .NET core everything compiles except for this line:

```
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
```

It won't compile because System.IdentityModel isn't available in .NET Core.

I discovered that if I acquire the user access token and the user name using this code instead it works for users in the *same* tenant as the service:

```
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity identity = 
    User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
string userAccessToken = identity.BootstrapContext as string;
string userName = (User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn))?.Value;
```

But for users in a *different* tenant (multi-tenant authentication), userAccessToken and userName are set to null.  What do I need to do differently to get this working for users coming from a different tenant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the reason userAccessToken and userName were coming back as null is because I was missing the SaveSigninToken parameter when calling UseJwtBearerAuthentication in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Tenant"]),
    Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Audience"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { SaveSigninToken = true, ValidateIssuer = false }
});
```

Without SaveSigninToken = true, the caller's access token and identity doesn't flow through in the case where the caller is from another tenant.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the `BootstrapContext` class to get the access_token, we can use the `HttpContext` in the controller directly to get the orignal access_token via code below:

```
var orignalToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers["authorization"][0].Split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: Good alternative.  Thanks.

Comment: This is shortcut rather than proper way. It doesn't work with encrypted JWT tokens for example.